# How to convert SAS functions to Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, sas, hiveql, sas-macro

How can I convert this SAS SQL Script that contains some specific SAS functions to Hive SQL ? I need to make those logic equivalences.
I read SAS docs but didn´t find any direct way to convert this create-select script.
Can anyone help me with this ?
Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE QUERYFORTEST_2 AS
   SELECT t1.date_h,
          t1.en_id,
          t1.eu_1,
          t1.eu_2,
          t1.eu_3,
          t1.eu_4,
            (INPUT(SUBSTR(t1.enc_id,ANYALNUM(t1.en_id),(ANYALPHA(t1.en_id) -1 )), 18. )) FORMAT=COMMA18. LABEL="enid" AS 'enid',
  (CASE
     WHEN MISSING (t1.eu_1)= 1
     THEN 0
     ELSE t1.eu_1
  END
  ) FORMAT=COMMA18. AS eu_1b,
  (CASE
         WHEN MISSING (t1.eu_2)= 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE t1.eu_2
      END

      ) FORMAT=COMMA18. AS eu_2b,
      (CASE
         WHEN MISSING (t1.eu_3)= 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE t1.eu_3
      END

      ) FORMAT=COMMA18. AS eu_3b,
      (CASE
         WHEN MISSING (t1.eu_4)= 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE t1.eu_4
      END

      ) FORMAT=COMMA18. AS eu_4b
FROM QUERYFORTEST_1 t1;
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything automatic. You need to go sql by sql and convert them. There should be some or other functions for all sas functionality.

Comment: I don´t mean automatic. In this case I need to somehow translate their logic into Hive SQL, but I don´t know how to do this equivalence.

Comment: Be specific.  Which functions do you not understand?  What did you try? How did it work out?

Comment: I Guess  @tom answered it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is SAS specific syntax related to attaching a FORMAT or a LABEL to the a few of the fields,

```
FORMAT=COMMA18.
LABEL="enid"
```

you can just remove that.

The MISSING() function tests if a variable is missing or not (comparing the result to 1 is superfluous since a value of 1 is already considered TRUE by SAS).  To test if a value is missing in generic SQL use the IS NULL construct.

```
WHEN t1.eu_3 IS NULL
```

So that just leaves the complex expression:

```
INPUT(
 SUBSTR(t1.enc_id
       ,ANYALNUM(t1.en_id)
       ,ANYALPHA(t1.en_id) -1 
       )
 , 18. 
)
AS 'enid'
```

So basically that is converting part of the EN_ID string into a number and calling it ENID instead.  I am not sure if either SAS or HIVE would approve of the single quotes around the target name.

So the SUBSTR() function should be available in HIVE (or some equivalent function.)  The INPUT() function you might need to translate into a CAST() function call instead.  But for teasing out which part of the value to convert into a number you might want to look at what tools HIVE has for running regular expressions.

You should look at some of the EN_ID values and figure our why the SAS code is trying to convert part of the value into a number instead of just leaving it as a string. I would be surprised if the given code even works.  Why would the length of the substring be related to the location of the first letter in the string?  If that was the case then why not make the start of the substring be the first character in the string?  Otherwise you might end up including the first letter in the value passed to the INPUT() function which would make it impossible to convert into a number. And if the first character of the string is a letter then you will pass SUBSTR() a length of zero.